# dragging from a sortable list to a drag and drop plugin

Tags: draggable, jquery-ui-sortable, jquery-ui-draggable, dynatree

I am trying to allow dragging from a sortable list to a dynatree.

My initial though was to specify something like this:

```
    $('#ews_pgs_clpbrd_items').sortable({
        connectToDynatree: true
    }).disableSelection();
```

dynatree does not register the drag and drop events for the sortable items. so I tried

```
    $("#ews_pgs_clpbrd_items").sortable().disableSelection();
    $("#ews_pgs_clpbrd_items li").draggable({
        connectToDynatree: true,
        connectToSortable: "#ews_pgs_clpbrd_items"
    });
```

This allows the items in the sortable list to be dragged to the dynatree but it no longer allows sorting. When I try to sort I get the following error.

> Cannot read property 'options' of undefined

This appears to just be a limitation on sortable since http://jsfiddle.net/7TTSG/3/ it happens even without dynatree.

Is there a way to pass the drag and drop option "connectToDynatree: true" in the sortable or a way to make drag and drop not break sortable?