# jQuery UI: cannot read property left of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I keep getting the error `cannot read property left of undefined` when I drag the sortable jQuery UI elements around. Everything is working like I intend but I keep getting the error and would like to fix the problem causing it.

The intent is to have a sortable list with multi-select capability so that you are not forced to drag one element at a time. Like I said that is working and I followed the code on [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hQnWG/480/)

The strange thing is when I created a codepen to include with this question I am not getting the error message in the console anymore. I tried codepen and jsfiddle. I realize it may be difficult to troubleshoot if you can not see the error for yourself but am hoping someone might be able to spot a mistake or give me suggestions on what to check.

Here is [my codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vNGYLa) and some code:

**EDIT:**
The problem has been solved thanks to a comment. I needed to change my jQuery version.

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">

<ul id="elePool" class="sortme">
    <li class="draggable element" data-element="1">sku</li>
    <li class="draggable element" data-element="2">type</li>
    <li class="draggable element" data-element="3">attribute_set</li>
</ul>

<ul id="eleGroups">
    <li class="sortme group attribute required" id="group-weight"></li>
    <li class="sortme group attribute required" id="group-visibility"></li>
    <li class="sortme group attribute" id="group-status"></li>
    <li class="sortme group attribute" id="group-short_description"></li>
</ul>
    <ul class='custom-menu' id="elementMenu">
        <li class='visibleElement' data-action="duplicate">Duplicate</li>
        <li class='visibleElement' data-action="delete">Delete</li>
        <li class='visibleElement' data-action="copy">Copy</li>
        <li class='visibleElement' data-action="cut">Cut</li>
    </ul>

    <ul class='custom-menu' id='attributeMenu'>
        <li class='visibleAttribute' data-action="paste">Paste</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
ul {
    padding: 0;
}

#elePool,
#eleGroups {
    float:left;
    margin-right:30px;
    width:300px;
    border:1px solid #808080;
    min-height:25px;
}
#eleGroups {
    min-height:300px;
}

li.selected {
    background-color: #DAA520 !important;
}

#eleGroups .group li,
#elePool li {
    border:1px solid #808080;
    background-color:#E0FFFF;
    line-height:25px;
    cursor: -webkit-grab;
    cursor: move;
    text-indent:15px;
    list-style: none;
}

#eleGroups > li {
    position:relative;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    min-height:100px; 
    border:1px dashed #D3D3D3;
    padding-top: 20px;
    list-style: none;
}

#eleGroups > li:after {
   position:absolute;
   top:1px;
   left:2px;
   font-size:16px;
   text-transform: uppercase;
   color: #808080;
}

li.group {
    float: left;
    width: 33.3%;
}

ul#eleGroups {
    width:50%;
}

.required {
    background-color:#FFEBE8;
}

.complete {
    background-color:#EEFFAA !important;
}

/* The whole thing */
.custom-menu {
    display: none;
    z-index: 1000;
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    white-space: nowrap;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    background: #FFF;
    color: #333;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 0;
}

/* Each of the items in the list */
.custom-menu li {
    padding: 8px 12px;
    cursor: pointer;
    list-style-type: none;
}

.custom-menu li:hover {
    background-color: #DEF;
}

#group-weight:after {content: 'weight'}
#group-visibility:after {content: 'visibility'}
#group-status:after {content: 'status'}
#group-short_description:after {content: 'short_description'}
```

JS:

```
function addElementMenu() {
    $('.element').on("contextmenu", function (e) {

        // Avoid the real one
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        //set clicked item
       clicked = $(this);
       parent = $(this).parent().attr('id');
        // Show contextmenu
        $("#elementMenu").finish().show().css({
            top: event.pageY + "px",
            left: event.pageX + "px",
            display: 'block'
        });
    });
}

function addAttributeMenu() {
    $('.attribute').on("contextmenu", function (e) {

        // Avoid the real one
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        //set clicked item
       clicked = $(this);
       parent = $(this).parent().attr('id');
        // Show contextmenu
        $("#attributeMenu").finish().show().css({
            top: event.pageY + "px",
            left: event.pageX + "px",
            display: 'block'
        });    
    });
}


$('.sortme').on('click', 'li', function(e) {
    if(e.ctrlKey || e.metaKey) {
        $(this).toggleClass("selected");
    } else {
        $(this).addClass("selected").siblings().removeClass('selected');
    }
}).sortable({
    connectWith: ".sortme",
    delay: 150,
    revert: 0,
    helper: function (e, item) {
        var helper = $('<li/>');
        if(!item.hasClass('selected')) {
            item.addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
        }
        var elements = item.parent().children('.selected').clone();
        item.data('multidrag', elements).siblings('.selected').remove();
        return helper.append(elements);
    },
    stop: function(e, info) {
        info.item.after(info.item.data('multidrag')).remove();
    },
    update: function(event, ui) {
        checkRequired(this);
    }
});

function checkRequired(elementToCheck) {
    if($(elementToCheck).hasClass('required')) {
        if($(elementToCheck).is(':empty')) {
            $(elementToCheck).removeClass('complete');
        } else {
            $(elementToCheck).addClass('complete');
        }
    }
}

//add the context menus
    addElementMenu();
    addAttributeMenu();

    // If the document is clicked somewhere
    $(document).bind("mousedown", function (e) {

        // If the clicked element is not the menu
        if (!$(e.target).parents(".custom-menu").length > 0) {

            // Hide it
            $(".custom-menu").hide(100);
        }
    });


    // If the menu element is clicked
    $(".custom-menu li").click(function(){

        // This is the triggered action name
        switch($(this).attr("data-action")) {

            // A case for each action. Your actions here
            case "duplicate": duplicateItem(clicked); break;
            case "delete": deleteItem(clicked); break;
            case "copy": copyItem(clicked); break;
            case "cut": cutItem(clicked); break;
            case "paste": pasteItem(); break;
        }

        // Hide it AFTER the action was triggered
        $(".custom-menu").hide(100);
      });
```

Comment: This seems like perhaps a typo in one of your jQuery selectors perhaps. Or like forgetting to add '.' to a class name selector. But with the give examples I don't believe you will get a valid answer.

Comment: What js file gives an error? jquery-ui?

Comment: @Zealander it is jQuery-UI specifically the `refreshPositions` function at this `item.left = p.left;`

Comment: @Joe, are you positive you're using latest jquery-ui?  I found various bug reports similar to you problem. Those bugs are fixed in 1.9.1:

Comment: @Zealander you just solved my problem I was using https://code.jquery.com/jquery-git2.min.js for my jQuery version. I just changed it to 1.11.3 and the errors went away!

Comment: @Joe, all well what ends well. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

When you load js file?
If you load js files above the dom elements you handle,
your javascript code `$( selector )` will not work properly.

Maybe Codepen and fiddle load your js files after dom elements, so the error will not occurs.

check your html file's javascript load point.

Many people likes following.

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>

    <body>

        <!-- your dom elements -->
        <script src="yourJavascript.js"></script>
    </body>

</html>
```

If you load js files just before `</body>`, you can use your dom elements in `yourJavascript.js`

Comment: I load everything in the head and wrap the code in a `$(document).ready()` the order of scripts are `jquery, jquery-ui, my-js`

Comment: Your code works well in my server. check my html file http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RWawmX
In my html, tt.js is your javascript part.
I did test in chrome browser v45, osX yesemite.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, although in a somewhat different scenario (I was adding items manually to a sortable list). My problem was also highly sensitive to timing and environment options, sometimes it ran ok, sometimes not.

[This stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20401180/jqueryui-draggable-sortable-bug-cannot-read-property-options-of-undefined) helped me onto the right track (I needed to clone the object before I added it to the list)

Answer (score 0):

**Please try to adding containment in sortable.**

**Default: false
Defines a bounding box that the sortable items are constrained to while dragging.**

Note: The element specified for containment must have a calculated width and height (though it need not be explicit). For example, if you have float: left sortable children and specify containment: "parent" be sure to have float: left on the sortable/parent container as well or it will have height: 0, causing undefined behavior.

**$( ".selector" ).sortable({
  containment: "parent"
});**

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried wrapping the whole thing in jQuery, which would delay execution until DOMReady.

```
$(function () { /*...YOUR CODE HERE...*/ });
```

Comment: Yes the entire script is wrapped in `$(document).ready(function()`

Comment: @Yamaha32088 I could not reproduce the issue. Copied your code form codepen to a local file, added the jQuery, and jQueryUI, if I wrapped it like you, it went smooth. As ssohjiro asked, the full source would be needed.

Comment: you can see the entire code by going back to the codepen http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vNGYLa

Comment: @Yamaha32088 Yes, but the codepen example did not produce the issue, as you mentioned above :)